# How do I use Visual Studio 2017 to only compile C code and not take into account c++?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

In the C language, you are not allowed to make declarations after the first functional statement, however, when I compile my program with this error, it still works and c++ takes over. How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: If you're referring to the requirement that all variables must be declared at the beginning of a scope, that hasn't been a thing in C since C90.

Comment: Since the C99 standard (released 20 years ago this year), you can have declarations in between statements as well. And Visual Studio support almost all of C99 these days.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want this behaviour. We're living in the 21 century.

Comment: It isn't an error. VS 2017 allows you to define a variable anywhere within any scope. What do you mean by "C++ takes over"?

Comment: Your source file names should end with the .c extension not .C++

Comment: @WeatherVane I suppose as in C99 variables can be declared elsewhere that at the beginning of a scope, he thinks it's compiling as c++.

Comment: It's not that C++ took over, but that C++ came up with some good ideas that C borrowed in later versions of the standard.

Comment: Also maybe use `#ifdef __cplusplus` / `#error misconfigured compiler` / `#endif`

Answer (score 2):

The C compiler used by Visual Studio 2017 is more or less C99 compliant.

In C99 variables can be declared elsewhere that at the beginning of a scope, just like in C++.

So this code snippet is a valid C99, but it's not valid C89:

```
int foo(void)
{
  printf("Hello. ");
  int bar = 2;
  printf("Bar = %d\n", bar);
}
```

This is valid C89:

```
int foo(void)
{
  int bar = 2;
  printf("Hello. ");
  printf("Bar = %d\n", bar);
}
```

More information here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C#C89